# binary string: unexpected end in precompiled chunk

Tags: c++, lua

I have following problem with ***Lua 5.1*** from the Ubuntu repositories. But the problem is the same with the Lua from *Hardy* (old) up to *Precise* (quite recent).

I want to precompile following little Lua code:

```
i = 0;
```

following code I use in my C++ program:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t *len;
    char **data;
} BS_DESCRIP;

static int hgl_lua_Writer(lua_State * /*l*/, const void *p, size_t sz, void *ud) {

    BS_DESCRIP *bd = (BS_DESCRIP *)ud;

    char *newData;

    if((newData = (char *)realloc(*(bd->data), (*(bd->len)) + sz))) {
        memcpy(newData + (*(bd->len)), p, sz);
        *(bd->data) = newData;
        *(bd->len) += sz;
    } else {
        free(newData);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

char *CompilerBase::luaCompile(char *script, size_t *scriptLen) const throw(Exception::LuaException) {

 char *byteCode = 0L;

 lua_State *l = Type::Lua::LuaTypeBase::m_luaInit.m_luaState;

 if(l) {
    size_t byteCodeLen = 0;
    int ret;

    if(!(ret = luaL_loadstring(l, script))) {
        BS_DESCRIP bd = { &byteCodeLen, &byteCode };

        lua_dump(l, hgl_lua_Writer, &bd);
        lua_pop(l, 1);

        logDebug("Rechecking pre-compiled Lua string...");
        ret = luaL_loadstring(l, byteCode);
    }

    if(ret) {
        if(ret == LUA_ERRSYNTAX) {
            throw Exception::LuaException(lua_tostring(l, -1));
        } else if(ret == LUA_ERRMEM) {
            throw Exception::LuaException("Lua memory allocation error");
        } else {
            throw Exception::LuaException("Lua unknown error");
        }
    } else {
        *scriptLen = byteCodeLen;
    }

 } else {
    throw Exception::LuaException("Lua hasn't been initialized");
 }

 return byteCode;
}
```

Any Lua code including the minimum code above fails already at "Rechecking" with the error

> binary string: unexpected end in precompiled chunk
>   but I can't find the error.

Where could be my error? I have no ideas :-(

Comment: Maybe your "error" is in your steadfast refusal to actually use *C++*. Outside of the fact that you seem to be using namespace or classes, this is all C-style code, with malloc, realloc, and so forth. Why aren't you putting this stuff into a `vector<char>` that you append to?

Comment: Or simply std::string.

Comment: It is simply because LUA interfaces best with C, therefore the hgl_lua_writer is C-Style and malloc/realloc,etc. I tried already with both, std::vector and std::string, but both to no avail.

Comment: @NicolBolas: did you already saw the other around 20000 lines of source code to claim I refuse "steadfast" C++? Sorry, but for LUA I even must surround it's "#include" within an ***extern "C"*** block.

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer, just because Lua i written in C doesn't mean you can't use C++ facilities when creating Lua helper functions. Let me put my version of Lua_Writer function in an answer. Now the problem is clearly either in what you're passing to luaL_loadstring or in the writer function, as there's nothing else between the two. I assume that you've checked that the initial string passed to luaL_loadstring is correct, so that leaves lua_Writer as the culprit.

Comment: @W.B. Is the discussion of C-style or not of just one function now that important?? -- The input to loadstring can be considered valid. If not I get the right error message. But my tiny example LUA is valid and even with that it fails. -- I suspect my error somewhere in either the writer or on how I process the compiled output in the second luaL_loadstring call. About the writer: std::vector as well as std::string I have tried, with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just, as promised, my version of lua writer function that I use to dump bytecode:

```
int lua_MemoryWriter(lua_State *lua, const void *p, size_t sz, void *ud)
{
    MemStreamBuf *buf = (MemStreamBuf*)ud;
    if (buf->sputn((const char*)p, sz) == sz)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Where `MemStreamBuf` is my implementation of `std::streambuf` that simply streams to a memory buffer.

But you can just as well do it with `std::string`

```
int lua_MemoryWriter(lua_State *lua, const void *p, size_t sz, void *ud)
{
      std::string *buf = (std::string*)ud;
      buf->append((const char*)p, sz);
      return 0;
}
```

Of course this doesn't deal with exceptions, if any are thrown, at this point.

**BIG FAT EDIT:**

**FACEPALM**

Bytecode contains `0`s inside. You need to call `luaL_loadbuffer` and give the actual buffer size due to null characters inside the string.

It's weekend already, slow thinking, sorry ;)!

Comment: I'll check it again. Version #2 is almost identical a former try of me, but only _almost_. -- But it seems to have tradition with my PC to crash always shortly after I asked a question here. Must repair something first :-/

Comment: Tried your std::string method with the same result. The problem must lay somewhere after writer and the __"recheck"__ luaL_loadstring.

Comment: ok that sounds better :-) At least the recheck works, now the execution has to work as well, but that is another part of my project.

Comment: Now I get a _bad header_ error, but that is a different building site and I have a guess why.

Comment: w.b., so you made my day :-) All works like charm, despite the fact that precompiled code can be larger than source code. But for increased speed it is totally acceptable.

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer, I'm glad I could help. The speed is only increased when loading the script, but you surely know that. As to the size, it is because Lua saves debug information with the bytecode. But when the code gets larger, the bytecode tends to get smaller than the string representation.

Comment: Note that pre-compiled bytecode is likely to be larger than source code in many cases, and there are tools out there that will process source code to remove comments, unneeded white space, and even rename things to short unique names to squeeze lots of bytes out of source code. Lua source is also more portable between platforms, as well as between versions of Lua itself.